# Releasing the camera within a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, camera

I am creating a simple Morse code app. The user can enter in text which is then translated to Morse and flashed in sequence on a new thread. I have implemented a for loop which is used to turn on/off the camera flash to represent the Morse sequence.

The problem is that when the user navigates away from the activity the on pause method releases the camera but i sometimes get the error 'method called after release'. I am not sure how to cancel the thread from running when the camera is released. I have already attempted to use a volatile Boolean value which is checked at the start of each loop iteration but if the loop is cancelled at any other time but the start then it results in an error.

Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions as to how i could solve this problem?

```
  public void flashTranslation(String message) {

    int offIntervalTime = 50;
    char[] cArray = message.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
        if (cArray[i] == '.') {
            turnOn();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d("One", "Two");
            }

            turnOff();

            try {
            Thread.sleep(offIntervalTime);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        } else if(cArray[i] == ' ')
        {
            Log.d("EMPTY!", "EMPTY!");
            try{

                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        else {

            try{
            turnOn();
            Thread.sleep(dash);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
            try{
            turnOff();
            Thread.sleep(offIntervalTime);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The right answer here is canceling the thread and using critical sections, or not using a thread at all.  Do you want the thread to continue the previous pulse if it comes back up, or to cancel and wait for new input?

Comment: I am unsure of any other way of doing this without the use of a thread. The user has the option of waiting until the current sequence has finished and then entering another sequence but if the user leaves the activity then the camera need to be released as there are other activities within the application that require it's use.

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my question.  But I'll give you an answer assuming that if the user leaves the app and comes back, you want to start over rather than continue midstream.  That makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is canceling the thread protecting against concurrent access via semaphore.  Every time you try to flash on the thread, you check if the thread is canceled.  Pseudocode:

```
Semaphore sem;

onPause(){
    sem.take();
    camera.turnOff();
    camera.release();
    thread.cancel();
    sem.give();
}

thread.run() {
  //This should be run before every call to turnOn or turnoff
   sem.take();
   if(isCanceled()) {
     return;
   }
   turnOn();
   sem.give();
}

onResume() {
  new Thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with the semaphore class. Would using a Boolean value before each call to turnOn and turnOff give a similar outcome?  I am unfamiliar with the semaphore class but i am going to look into it now and see how i can implement it.

Comment: No.  A semaphore is a cross thread concurrency mechanism.  Its built into Android/Java, no need to build it.  Imagine the Semaphore as a very special boolean.  When take is called, if the boolean is true it sets it to false and returns immediately.  If its false it will pause the thread until someone else sets it true.  Give sets it to true.  But it does this all in a thread safe manner.  Using it like this assures no two threads can touch the camera variable at the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and answer. I have looked into the semaphore class and its looks like it will do the trick. I appreciate the help.